# Inner button onClick event not being fired with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi I have something like this in a React application:

```
<li onClick={this.props.onToggleTodo}>
    Todo
    <button  onClick={this.props.onRemove}>Remove</button>
<li>
```

But when I click on remove button... the handler **onToggleTodo** is fired but **onRemove** isn't.

I fixed by doing this on handler:

```
onToggleTodo = t => (e) => {
    if(e.target.tagName == 'LI'){
        this.setState({done: true});
    }
}
```

It wasn't firing because of **setState** because it makes React render again...

That is NOT the best way, RIGHT?????

Here is the [demo](https://github.lucaskatayama.com/learn-react/react/todo/) and the [code](https://github.com/lucaskatayama/learn-react/tree/master/react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the onToggleTodo is on the li and the li is a container for the button... You might want to try working as following:

```
<li>
    <span onClick={this.props.onToggleTodo}>Todo</span>
    <button onClick={this.props.onRemove}>Remove</button>
<li>
```

**edit**

If you *REALLY* want to work the way you were doing at first, I think this should work also:

```
<li {todoToggled ? onClick={this.props.onToggleTodo}}>
    Todo
    <button  onClick={this.props.onRemove}>Remove</button>
<li>

onToggleTodo = () => {
  this.setState({
    todoToggled = true
  })
  //Rest of your code
}

onRemove = () => {
  this.setState({
    todoToggled = false
  })
  //Rest of your code
}
```

I'm not 100% if the syntax is correct here because I'm writing this without any feedback, but I think it's headed in the correct direction.

Comment: I thought that but... I want the li area to be clickable...
Even if span takes all width possible it would not take around the button...

Comment: sure you can make the li position: relative; span width: 100%; height 100%; position absolute, button position absolute and then put it where you want?

Comment: Probably the best solution so far...
So if I want separated events... DO separated objects in the DOM..

Comment: It's very logical... If you see the DOM elements as layers, then the li will always be over the button, which will always toggle the todo... Now that I think of it, I might have a solution you prefer... Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong... Are you trying to put onClick event if toggle == true ...

If yes...  when todo is done .. I can't undone???

hey.. here is the demo https://github.lucaskatayama.com/learn-react/react/todo/#/todo
I want that entire blank area (row) be clickable to set todo.done = true...

Comment: The thing I just tried to do is:

if todoToggled = true, add an onClick on this element. if it's not true (which you have set after running onToggleTodo the first time), there won't be an onClick, which means only the onClick of the button will be executed.

But because you want to be able to click on your li again when you have clicked your button, you have to set todoToggled to false after clicking on the button... That should make it work I honestly think

To answer your question: Yes it wíll be able to be undone.

Answer (score 0):

its javascript.. so..

```
onToggleTodo = t => (e) => {    
      this.setState({done: true});
}

onRemove = t => (e) => {    
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log(e.target);
}
```

Comment: Nops... onRemove it not even called because onToggleTodo is called before... and then this.setState makes react re-render...